# Меню с картинками Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Ребят подскажите в каком направлении идти, что-бы дать возможность админу сайта добавлять к пунктам меню картинки при формировании меню?
Варианты с плагинами интересуют мало.

Answer (score 0):

Есть масса замечательных плагинов. Вот например один из них - Menu Icons (https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/menu-icons/screenshots/).

Так же можешь в ручную, на определённый пункт меню, например:
 `class="cat-item cat-item-248"`
в файле `.ccs` к этому классу задавать `background-image`c левым позиционированием

Comment: Да плагины то понятно, но мне больше научиться это делать, чем пользоваться готовым.... хотя как вариант разобрать пару плагинов......

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Вы меня малость не поняли, конечно можно в css задать необходимые правила..... Но меня интересует добавление полей настроек непосредственно в админку, что - бы при формировании меню админ мог выбрать картинку которая будет отображаться.